# Передача UTF-8 строки из Python в С++ DLL

Tags: c++, python, utf-8

Пытаюсь передать строку UTF-8 (кириллица) из Python на вход с++ DLL

Код на Python:

```
from ctypes import *
import os
nDLL = CDLL('LingProcDll.dll')
ffff = open('D:\\1\\test.txt')
ffff1=str(ffff.read())
b_ffff=ffff1.encode('utf-8')
nDLL.LP_CreateLPObject.restype=c_void_p
pLP=nDLL.LP_CreateLPObject()
nDLL.LP_GetLiteralErrorsList.restype=c_int
nDLL.LP_GetLiteralErrorsList.argtypes=[c_void_p,c_char_p,c_char_p]
tone2=nDLL.LP_GetLiteralErrorsList(pLP,b_lang,b_ffff)
```

b_ffff сдержит следующее :

> b'\xd0\xa0\xd1\x9a\xd0\xa0\xd1\x91\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb6\xd0\xa0\xd2\x91\xd0\xa0\xc2\x
>   b0\xd0\xa0\xd0\x85\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb0\xd0\xa1\xd0\x82\xd0\xa0\xd1\x95\xd0\xa0\xd2\x
>   91\xd0\xa0\xd0\x85\xd0\xa1\xe2\x80\xb9\xd0\xa0\xe2\x84\x96
>   \xd0\xa1\xd0\x83\xd0\ xa0\xd1\x95\xd0\xa1\xd0\x8b\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb7
>   \xd0\xa0\xd0\x85\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb5\xd0
>   \xa0\xc2\xb1\xd0\xa1\xe2\x80\xb9\xd0\xa0\xc2\xbb
>   \xd0\xa0\xd1\x94\xd0\xa0\xd1\x9
>   5\xd0\xa0\xd0\x85\xd0\xa1\xd0\x8a\xd0\xa0\xd1\x94\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb0\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb
>   1\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb5\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb6\xd0\xa1\xe2\x80\xa0\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb5\xd0\xa0\xd
>   0\x86 (ISU)
>   \xd0\xa0\xd0\x86\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb5\xd0\xa0\xd2\x91\xd0\xa0\xc2\xb5\xd0

.......

Видно что это  UTF-8

Вот функция с++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int LP_GetLiteralErrorsList(void *pLP, const char *pLang,const char *pInText){   

    cout<<pInText<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Результат такой:

> ╨а╤Ъ╨а╤С╨а┬╢╨а╥С╨а┬░╨а╨Е╨а┬░╨б╨В╨а╤Х╨а╥С╨а╨Е╨бтА╣╨атДЦ
>   ╨б╨Г╨а╤Х╨б╨Л╨а┬╖ ╨а╨Е╨а┬╡ ╨а┬▒╨бтА╣╨а┬╗
>   ╨а╤Ф╨а╤Х╨а╨Е╨б╨К╨а╤Ф╨а┬░╨а┬▒╨а┬╡╨а┬╢╨бтАа╨а┬╡╨а╨Ж (ISU) ╨а╨Ж╨а┬╡╨а
>   ╥С╨а┬╡╨бтАЪ ╨б╨В╨а┬░╨б╨Г╨б╨Г╨а┬╗╨а┬╡╨а╥С╨а╤Х╨а╨Ж╨а┬░╨а╨Е╨а╤С╨а┬╡
>   ╨а╤Ч╨б╨В╨а╤Х╨а╤ С╨б╨Г╨бтВм╨а┬╡╨б╨Г╨бтАЪ╨а╨Ж╨а╤С╨б╨П ╨а╨Е╨а┬░
>   ╨б╨В╨а┬░╨а┬╖╨а╤Ш╨а╤С╨а╨Е╨а╤Ф╨а┬╡ ╨а ╤Ч╨а┬╡╨б╨В╨а┬╡╨а╥С
>   ╨а╤Ф╨а╤Х╨б╨В╨а╤Х╨бтАЪ╨а╤Ф╨а╤Х╨атДЦ ╨а╤Ч╨б╨В╨а╤Х╨а╤Ц╨б╨В╨а┬░╨а
>   ╤Ш╨а╤Х╨атДЦ ╨б╤У ╨бтАЮ╨а┬╡╨а╤Ц╨б╤У╨б╨В╨а╤С╨б╨Г╨бтАЪ╨а╤Х╨а╤Ф ╨а╨Е╨а┬░
>   ╨бтАб╨а┬╡╨а ╤Ш╨а╤Ч╨а╤С╨а╤Х╨а╨Е╨а┬░╨бтАЪ╨а┬╡ ╨а╤Ш╨а╤С╨б╨В╨а┬░.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что случилось с кодировкой и как восстановить исходную строку (как та которая подавалась на вход)?
Со строкой ничего я не делал.

Answer (score 4):

С кодировкой всё в порядке. Результат выглядит ровно так, как должна выглядеть строка в кодировке utf-8 после вывода в консоль с кодировкой cp866. Либо передавайте строку в кодировке соответствующей кодировке консоли

```
b_ffff = ffff1.encode('cp866')
```

либо перед запуском изменяйте кодировку консоли

```
chcp 65001
python script.py
```

либо доработайте функцию `LP_GetLiteralErrorsList` так, чтобы она меняла

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int LP_GetLiteralErrorsList(void *pLP, const char *pLang,const char *pInText){   
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, 1024);
    cout << pInText << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*Упрощённый пример*

Comment: либо доработайте функцию `LP_GetLiteralErrorsList` так, чтобы она перекодировала из UTF-8 в привычную для windows кодировку.