# Не получается конвертировать строку, полученную из бинарного фала в UTF-8

Tags: c++, кодировка, utf-8

Возникли проблемы со строкой, полученной из файла. В файле содержится строка

> РњРёР¶РґР°РЅР°СЂРѕРґРЅС‹Р№ СЃРѕСЋР· РЅРµР±С‹Р» РєРѕРЅСЊРєР°Р±РµР¶С†РµРІ (ISU) РІРµРґРµС‚ СЂР°СЃСЃР»РµРґРѕРІР°РЅРёРµ РїСЂРѕРёСЃС€РµСЃС‚РІРёСЏ РЅР° СЂР°Р·РјРёРЅРєРµ РїРµСЂРµРґ РєРѕСЂРѕС‚РєРѕР№ РїСЂРѕРіСЂР°РјРѕР№ Сѓ С„РµРіСѓСЂРёСЃС‚РѕРє РЅР° С‡РµРјРїРёРѕРЅР°С‚Рµ РјРёСЂР°.

Она получена путем преобразования строки UTF-8  в байтовую строку средствами python. [[Передача UTF-8 строки из Python в С++ DLL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/985165/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-utf-8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-python-%D0%B2-%D0%A1-dll][1])

Исходный текст в UTF-8 такой:

> Международный союз конькобежцев (ISU) ведет расследование происшествия на разминке перед короткой программой у фигуристок на чемпионате мира. ...

я читаю из файла потом пытаюсь конвертировать средствами Qt,но строка не изменяется , подскажите что я делаю не так.

Вот код:

```
        std::ifstream f(filepath);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << f.rdbuf();
        const char* decodeStr=ss.str().c_str();
        QString text = QString ::fromUtf8(decodeStr);
```

Судя по примерам работы с UTF-8 переменная text должна содержать исходный текст , но это не так. Подскажите как решить проблему пожалуйста.

Все спасибо, проблема решена. На самом деле проблема была не в коде на с++, действительно из pythona уже подавалась информация с неверной кодировкой. Соответственно из фала читались данные в неправильной кодировке. В чем проблема была опишу тут. [[Передача UTF-8 строки из Python в С++ DLL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/985165/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-utf-8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-python-%D0%B2-%D0%A1-dll][1])

Comment: в файле у вас содержится мусор

Comment: У stringstream нет метода c_str(). Ваш код нерабочий.

Comment: @VTT, я ничего не менял после преобразования функцией python .encode('utf-8')

Comment: @zenden2k, спасибо, ошибку я исправил, но проблему это естественно не решило

Comment: А что такое "байтовая строка"? Вы подаете содержимое файла на вход метода fromUtf8, поэтому там должно быть именно UTF8. Если Python отдает что-то в другой кодировке (похоже на CP1251), это необходимо преобразовать в UTF8. Только зачем UTF8 из питона преобразовывать в что-то, а затем снова в UTF8 для QString? Почему напрямую не передать?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight , спасибо за ответ. Байтовая строка тут описана, например  [ссылка](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/bajty-bytes-i-bytearray.html) . Python формирует байтовую строку именно в UTF-8.  Выглядит примерно так (\xd0\xa0\xd1\x9a\xd0\) 
 При передаче в с++, через параметр const char * , получается то, что я написал в вопросе. Вообще предается все напрямую, этот пример я написал для упрощения.

Comment: Судя по документации https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details переменная `text` должна содержать текст в кодировке UTF-16.

Comment: @Герман Борисов , как я понимаю к методу fromUtf8 это не относится

Comment: А, я понял. У вас в файле нормальный UTF8, просто вы пытаетесь его интерпретировать как CP1251, поэтому получаете иероглифы как на первой цитате. Так что проблема не в кодировке, а в чем-то другом. А как вы понимаете, что не конвертировалось? Что вы потом делаете с переменной text?

Comment: Раз уж у Вас Qt есть, сделайте через `QFile::readAll` чтение в `QByteArray` массива байт, и его уже конвертируйте в QString с использованием кодека или `QString::fromUtf8` [пруф](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8-1). А так вы используете std::string из stl, полученный из `stringstream`, а как там работа с кодировками происходит я не знаю.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight , не совсем так, записывал в файл, то что передается python ом и то, что принимается функцией С++ , это 2 разные кодировки (открывал NotePad++). Python предает байтовую строку в UTF-8, а с++ принимает ее уже перекодированную в cp1251. По крайней мере на это похоже очень

Comment: @vegorov , я попробовал, на выходе получается другая кодировка , уже 3-я   по счету и тоже не верная.

Comment: @ФедорИванович `QFile file(filepath); file.open(); auto ba = filre.readAll(); auto s = QString::fromUtf8(ba);` выдаёт вам что-то не то? Значит, как уже заметил MSDN.WhiteKnight, дело не в кодировке. У вас где-то ещё проблема. При условии что в файле utf-8, а не что-то ещё. Если там не utf8, попробуйте с помощью iconv подобрать кодировку того, что в файле

Comment: @ФедорИванович, мой комментарий относится к словам "Судя по примерам работы с UTF-8 переменная text должна содержать исходный текст".

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете метод c_str() у временного объекта.

Попробуйте так:

```
ss << f.rdbuf();
QString text = QString::fromUtf8(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: К сожалению разницы нет, что выдавалось то и выдается.